# sockets module in python not properly sending requests?? sockets newbie here

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, http-headers

so i have been trying to create a script for a capture the flag level, and lately i have been completely stumped as to how this has not been working out.

```
#
# Connect to alien server ('localhost', 10000)
#
# Then send each of these values...
# USER
# aliensignal
# PASS
# unlockserver
# SEND
# moonbase
# END
# ...and receive the response from each.
#
# Note: You must receive data back from the server after you send each value
#
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.connect(('localhost', 10000))

header = "USER: aliensignal"
header1 = "PASS: unlockserver"
header2 = "SEND: moonbase"
header3 = "END"




req = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\{}\r\n\r\n".format(header)
req1 = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\{}\r\n\r\n".format(header1)
req3 = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\{}\r\n\r\n".format(header2)
req4 = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\{} \r\n\r\n".format(header3)
request1 = bytes(req, "utf-8")
sock.send(request1)
response = sock.recv(2048)
print(response)
request2 = bytes(req1, "utf-8")
sock.send(request2)
response2 = sock.recv(2048)
print(response2)
request3 = bytes(req3, "utf-8")
sock.send(request3)
response3 = sock.recv(2048)
print(response3)
request4 = bytes(req4, "utf-8")
sock.send(request4)
response4 = sock.recv(2048)
print(response4)






sock.close()
```

I try to setup the socks variable to be used to call to for socket operations, and then i try to define all of the requests that will be made, and type-cast them into bytes type. and i send the requests while waiting for a response, however none is given, and the output just remains blank[screenshot of code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IY7q.png)

ive tried to combine the type-casted request values into a single byte value and then using the `socks.sendall(val)` to no avail, ive tried to put the values itself into a single string to no avail

Comment: Does the assignment say to add POST / HTTP/1.1? Does the assignment say to put the USER/PASS/SEND and the aliensignal/unlockserver/moonbase on one line with a `:`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here since the task is not clearly defined. From the comments in your code it looks like that you should simply send messages on the sockets, but instead your are trying to do something which resembles HTTP but isn't actually proper HTTP. So it is not clear if your documentation of what you are trying to wrong or your implementation or both - at least they don't match.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).